# Calling selfhosted WCF service from Windows Phone 8 Emulator

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-8, hyper-v, self-hosting, windows-phone-8-emulator

My selfhosted WCF wervice works fine with any browser on the domain, and also with a WinForm client.  In a Windows Phone 8 app I can create Service References OK.  Trying to consume the service from within the app running in the emulator it causes the System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.

What I have done:

- allowed URL registration
- firewall inbound rule for the specified port
- enabled WCF Services, HTTP Activation (Windows Features)

In the Hyper-V settings for the Emulator it lists 4 network adapters: Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch, Intel...Gigabit Network Connection Virtual Switch and 2 VMware related switches.

Can the presence of VMware cause this problem?  (I have stopped the (4) VMware related services.)

What else can I check or do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a full day of working on the issue (not knowing anything about Hyper-V didn't help) I (we) worked out the problem:

In this particular, but quite common setup, both Ethernet and Wireless Network Adapters were enabled, and Ethernet ranked above Wireless, as you do to give the cable connection precedence over wireless when both are available.

Even though the Ethernet cable was disconnected at the time the Emulator was started/created, Hyper-V created Ethernet as the *only* external Network adapter to use.  But the because there was no cable, the adapter was physically disabled and the local WCF service (which was running on the wireless network) could not be found.

Disabling the Ethernet (hardware) adapter (Control Panel), then deleting the emulator, and reconstructing it by launching a phone app in VS fixed the connection issue.  On inspection the Wireless adapter is then assigned as the external adapter ("Virtual Switch") to use.

Hope that helps someone.